# onBeforeUnload suddenly not working as expected

Tags: javascript, browser, onbeforeunload

I was using this snippet for almost 2 years. It was fine then, until I saw it
was not working today on `Google Chrome version 51.0.2704.103m`.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    return "Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
});
```

It doesn't show my custom message but instead just show:

`Changes you made may not be saved.`

Is overriding onbeforeunload message is still supported on our browsers? Because this issue is same with `Mozilla Firefox version 47.0.1`.

Or, am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome from Version 51 onwards no longer supports custom messages on beforeunload.

*A window’s onbeforeunload property may be set to a function that returns a string that is shown to the user in a dialog box to confirm that the user wants to navigate away. This was intended to prevent users from losing data during navigation. Unfortunately, it is often used to scam users.*

Details [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/chrome-51-deprecations?hl=en#remove-custom-messages-in-onbeforeload-dialogs)