# Custom message when closing the browser/tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me on how to customize the alert message when closing the browser/tab?
I have tried all other codes in all forums, no luck. It displays the default alert message of the browser.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
var confirmationMessage = "Warning! Do not close, save first";

(e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
sendkeylog(confirmationMessage);
return confirmationMessage; //Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.});
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the snippet you posted contains a typo – the `});` for the event binding are part of the comment. This may be causing a SyntaxError, preventing the engine from using the code at all. (If this typo is only present in your post, please edit to correct it.)

Comment: There isn't a "default alert message" for `beforeunload`. The default is to silently allow the user to leave. Does your site/application have any other uses of the event that may be setting a different message? The browser will only show one of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onBeforeUnload suddenly not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428636/onbeforeunload-suddenly-not-working-as-expected)